# How can I extract text with re.findall?

Tags: python, text

## I want to

- Extract a country name from a HTML file
- I have made a txt file from the HTML source

## What I have tried

- https://www.flightsfrom.com/WUH/destinations
- I have written the code below

```
import re

f = open('/Users/User/Programming/plotly.csv/country_name.txt')
data1 = f.read()
print(re.findall('data_country\=(\".+\")', data1))
print(re.findall('a(.*)b', 'axyzb'))
```

The txt file looks like:
[image]

But the code just gives me this result:

[image]

I think this is the problem with a regular expression.

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: `data_country` is not the same thing as `data-country`.

Comment: Use the `.+?` (non-greedy) instead of `.+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
print(re.findall('data-country\=(\".+\")', strTmp))
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(re.findall('data-country\=(\".+?\")', data1))`
was exactly what I needed.

`print(re.findall('data-country\=(\".+\")', data1))`
gave me too long texts that I was not looking for.

I will not take a screenshot next time. Instead, I will copy and text the codes.
Thank you for letting me know.